# Help with formula - syntax error

Tags: formula, formula-field

I'm trying to say if an opportunity goes from Stage 4 OR Stage 5 to Lost, mark the checkbox field ("Stage 4 or 5 Lost") as true.

Getting a error: The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Extra ','

Help?

```
AND (
        OR (
            ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName) = "Stage 4 - Sell"), 
            ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE([Opportunity].StageName) = "Stage 5 – Negotiate"))
        ),
        ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName = "Lost"),
        [Opportunity].Stage_4_or_5_Lost__c <> true
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ISPICKVAL` takes two arguments separated by a comma, but you have instead tried using an equals sign.

**Incorrect**

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(...) = "value")
```

**Correct**

```
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(...), "value")
```